# How do addAll in TreeSet and HashSet really work?

Tags: java, hashset, treeset

When I added my datas on the treeSet I lost almost all my datas. It seems that I have only the first element of my set.

I read this question [Hashset vs Treeset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1463284/hashset-vs-treeset) for an code optimization and I tried to do something like them. But I didn't really succeed.

Input :

```
int iValue = 0;

    HashSet<TagResult> results = new HashSet<TagResult>();
    for(Document doc : docs) {
        NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("TEXT");

        for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {
            Node nNode = nList.item(temp);
            if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
                iValue = searchWords.searchOnTag(eElement, szSearch);
                if(iValue > 0) {
                    results.add(new TagResult(eElement, iValue));
                }
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Set :\n-------------------------");
    for(TagResult result : results) {
        System.out.println(getTagValue("Tag",result.getElement()));
    }
    Set<TagResult> sortedResult = new TreeSet<TagResult>(new Comparator<TagResult>() {

        public int compare(TagResult e1, TagResult e2) {
            return e2.getValue() - e1.getValue();
        }
    });

    sortedResult.addAll(results);

    System.out.println("Sorted Result :\n-------------------------");
    for(TagResult result : sortedResult) {
        System.out.println(getTagValue("Tag",result.getElement()));
}
```

The execution result give me that :

Output

Set :

```
TXT_KEY_RELIGION_POSITIF_MEDIAN_05
TXT_KEY_RELIGION_POSITIF_MEDIAN_02
TXT_KEY_RELIGION_POSITIF_04
TXT_KEY_RELIGION_POSITIF_06
TXT_KEY_RELIGION_POSITIF_05
TXT_KEY_RELIGION_POSITIF_03
TXT_KEY_RELIGION_POSITIF_MEDIAN_06
TXT_KEY_RELIGION_POSITIF_MEDIAN_01
TXT_KEY_RELIGION_POSITIF_MEDIAN_04
TXT_KEY_RELIGION_POSITIF_MEDIAN_08
TXT_KEY_RELIGION_POSITIF_MEDIAN_03
TXT_KEY_RELIGION_POSITIF_02
TXT_KEY_RELIGION_POSITIF_07
TXT_KEY_RELIGION_POSITIF_01
TXT_KEY_RELIGION_POSITIF_MEDIAN_09
TXT_KEY_RELIGION_POSITIF_MEDIAN_07
```

Sorted Result :

```
TXT_KEY_RELIGION_POSITIF_MEDIAN_05
```

I don't understand why I have this problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would imagine that

```
e2.getValue() - e1.getValue();
```

returns 0 for all the items in your set which are then considered equal. Try printing `tag.getValue()` for your tags to check if it is the case.

Extract from [`TreeSet` javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) (emphasis mine):

> Note that the ordering maintained by a set (whether or not an explicit comparator is provided) must be consistent with equals if it is to correctly implement the Set interface. (See Comparable or Comparator for a precise definition of consistent with equals.) This is so because the Set interface is defined in terms of the equals operation, but **a TreeSet instance performs all element comparisons using its compareTo** (or compare) method, so **two elements that are deemed equal by this method are, from the standpoint of the set, equal**. The behavior of a set is well-defined even if its ordering is inconsistent with equals; it just fails to obey the general contract of the Set interface.