# Interchanging HashSet and TreeSet

Tags: java, set, comparable

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Hashset vs Treeset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1463284/hashset-vs-treeset)

Can you use `HashSet` and `TreeSet` interchangeably? If I exchanged `TreeSet` for `Hashset` and vice versa in a program what issues would there be? Im aware you need to implement `Comparable` for a `TreeSet`.

Comment: what do you mean by interchange? can you write a sample?

Comment: PS I have a general understanding of how both work (pros, cons etc) but just want to know if there are any other things I should look out for.

Comment: Follow this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1463284/hashset-vs-treeset

Comment: @thinksteep if I had a program that used HashSet and simply changed it to TreeSet what issues would there be.

Comment: @Dave That depends on the intention of the program!

Comment: @adarshr If I had a very basic program that worked correctly using HashSet and I replaced HashSet for TreeSet would I expect it to work or would I have to make other changes? I know it is a vague question and the answer is probably yes unless I want an ordered set then would have to make changes to the program. Any other thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If some API requires `Set`, it absolutely doesn't matter which implementation you pass. If it requires concrete type (unlikely), you can't mix them.

In general, they difference is in performance (`HashSet` is faster) but this shouldn't affect how your program behaves and in order. Order of items in `HashSet` is unpredictable. If your program relies on any such order, it should rather use `LinkedHashSet` or `TreeSet`.

Comment: Thanks Tomasz, it is a question from a tutorial I am working on and is very vague, I guess that could be the point of the question to test your knowledge of the scenarios where you should use HashSet and where to use a TreeSet.

Answer (score 2):

`HashSet` and `TreeSet` are both `Set`s. They are mostly interchangeable, but keep in mind `TreeSet` is also a [`SortedSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html) and thus its elements must implement `Comparable`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your set to be ordered, you should use `TreeSet`. If you use a `HashSet` instead, you'll get unpredictable results for operations that rely on the ordering.

On another hand, a `HashSet` is much faster than a `TreeSet` if order is not something you worry about.