# how to make a Set to be empty

Tags: java, set

I want to initialize my set to be empty (not null), can anyone help me?
Here is my code

```
public class Graph {
private Set<Vertex> vertices;

public Graph() {
    vertices = {};
}
```

I know that this is a wrong way to do that, but couldn't do anything else

Comment: vertices = new HashSet<Vertex>();??

Answer (score 4):

Set is an *interface*. You need to decide on the *implementation* required, and then construct using a no-args constructor. e.g.

```
vertices = new HashSet<Vertex>();
```

or

```
vertices = new TreeSet<Vertext>();
```

See [this SO question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1463284/hashset-vs-treeset) for more info on `TreeSet` vs `HashSet`. Given that `Set` is an interface, any number of implementations could exist (you could even write your own) but I suspect you'll want one of these two to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

You need to execute a constructor:

```
public Graph() {
  vertices = new HashSet<>();
}
```

`Set` is an interface definition, so you will need to pick a concrete implementation of `Set`.  `HashSet` is one such implementation, but `TreeSet` is another (`TreeSet` is actually an implementation of a `SortedSet`).

Answer (score 1):

```
public Graph(){  
  vertices = new HashSet<Vertex>();  
}
```

or

```
public Graph(){  
  vertices = new TreeSet<Vertex>();  
}
```

Comment: or `new HashSet<>();` in Java 7

Comment: @Reimeus:I am still "stuck" in Java 6

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
vertices = {};
```

With

```
vertices = new HashSet<Vertex>();
```

This will initialize an empty `HashSet` for your `Set` interface