# java collection sort issue

Tags: java, collections, compare

i use simple comperator and get exception and don't know what to do

this is how i call:

```
try {
   Collections.sort(this.closePositions, new PositionComperator());
}
catch(Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

this is the comperator:

```
  public class PositionComperator implements Comparator<DataResponse> {

    @Override
    public int compare( DataResponse pos1, DataResponse pos2) {

        if (pos1.openTime >= pos2.openTime) {
            return 1;
        } 
        else {
            return -1;
        }// returning 0 would merge keys

    }

   }
```

this is the exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract!
at java.util.TimSort.mergeLo(Unknown Source)
at java.util.TimSort.mergeAt(Unknown Source)
at java.util.TimSort.mergeCollapse(Unknown Source)
at java.util.TimSort.sort(Unknown Source)
at java.util.TimSort.sort(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Arrays.sort(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Collections.sort(Unknown Source)
at GTTask.RefreshIdentityHistory.call(RefreshIdentityHistory.java:59)
at GTTask.RefreshIdentityHistory.call(RefreshIdentityHistory.java:1)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: `sort` can't cause elements to get merged. Though if you were to use a `Set`, it would be a different story.

Comment: can you provide code of PositionComperator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you get this error is that when it sorted two items they changed order. You should also include the case where it is equal.

Preferably do:

```
return po1.openTime - pos2.opentime;
```

Or do

```
if (pos1.openTime > pos2.openTime) {
    return 1;
} 
else if (pos1.openTime < pos2.openTime) {
    return -1;
} else {
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what does "return 0" will cause?

Comment: This means that they are equal and they will not be sorted. Have a look at the java doc for the compare method.

Answer (score 2):

If two values `x` and `y` have the same `openTime`, then `compare(x, y)` and `compare(y, x)` will both return 1, which violates the contract of [`compare`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare%28T,%20T%29):

> The implementor must ensure that `sgn(compare(x, y)) == -sgn(compare(y, x))` for all `x` and `y`.

You haven't ensured that.

You need to consider what you want to happen when the `openTime` values are the same - either return 0, or have *some* consistent notion of which value should come before the other. Do you have some secondary comparison you could perform, for example?

Comment: @user502967: No, for exactly the reason I gave: if the two values are equal, you'll get 1 when comparing them both ways. Look at the contract for `compare`.

Answer (score 1):

you can use treeSet. İt is sort it for you. And there is compare method. for example

```
TreeSet<Double> sortedSet = new TreeSet<Double>();
```

for example compare it

```
TreeSet<Double> set = new TreeSet<Rock>(new Comparator<Double>()
public int compare(Double a, Double b){
                return a.value - b.value;
            }
        }
```

Comment: why to use tree sort on list?

Comment: you can look this topic why you should use treeset. Treeset is directly sort and compare it you dont need another method and you can see more easy. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1463284/hashset-vs-treeset