# Is iterating through a TreeSet slower than iterating through a HashSet in Java?

Tags: java, iteration, hashset, treeset

I'm running some benchmarks. One of my tests depends on order, so I'm using a TreeSet for that. My second test doesn't, so I'm using a HashSet for it.

I know that insertion is slower for the TreeSet. But what about iterating through all elements?

Comment: Why not use a `timer` and find it for yourself?

Comment: Considering a HashSet uses a hash table, I would say yes.

Answer (score 1):

`TreeSets` internally uses `TreeMaps` which are `Red Black Trees` (special type of `BST`) .

`BST` Inorder Traversal is `O(n)`

`HashSets` internally uses `HashMaps` which use an `array` for holding Entry objects.

Here also traversal should be `O(n)` .

Unless you write a benchmark it is going to be difficult to prove which is faster.

Answer (score 0):

From a similar post ([Hashset vs Treeset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1463284/hashset-vs-treeset)):

**HashSet is much faster than TreeSet (constant-time versus log-time for most operations like add, remove and contains) but offers no ordering guarantees like TreeSet.**

### HashSet:

- class offers constant time performance for the basic operations (add, remove, contains and size).
- it does not guarantee that the order of elements will remain constant over time
- iteration performance depends on the *initial capacity* and the *load factor* of the HashSet.

  - It's quite safe to accept default load factor but you may want to specify an initial capacity that's about twice the size to which you expect the set to grow.

### TreeSet:

- guarantees log(n) time cost for the basic operations (add, remove and contains)
- guarantees that elements of set will be sorted (ascending, natural, or the one specified by you via it's constructor)
- doesn't offer any tuning parameters for iteration performance
- offers a few handy methods to deal with the ordered set like `first()`, `last()`, `headSet()`, and `tailSet()` etc

### Important points:

- Both guarantee duplicate-free collection of elements
- It is generally faster to add elements to the HashSet and then convert the collection to a TreeSet for a duplicate-free sorted traversal.
- None of these implementation are synchronized. That is if multiple threads access a set concurrently, and at least one of the threads modifies the set, it must be synchronized externally.
- **LinkedHashSet** is in some sense intermediate between `HashSet` and `TreeSet`. Implemented as a hash table with a linked list running through it, however **it provides insertion-ordered iteration which is not same as sorted traversal guaranteed by TreeSet**.

So choice of usage depends entirely on your needs but I feel that even if you need an ordered collection then you should still prefer HashSet to create the Set and then convert it into TreeSet.

- e.g. `Set<String> s = new TreeSet<String>(hashSet);`

Comment: this is a very thorough answer, but doesn't at all seem to address the OP's actual question...

Comment: hmm, i disagree.  this answer clearly addresses iteration between a HashSet and a TreeSet, albeit in a more vague sense than perhaps what OP would like.  from the second bullet point of the 'Important Points' section: "It is generally faster to add elements to the HashSet and then convert the collection to a TreeSet for a duplicate-free sorted traversal."

Comment: well, that part of the answer is pretty much flat out wrong.  what's the point of the overhead of adding to a HashSet first?  that's entirely useless overhead if you are going to copy to a TreeSet after the fact (well, unless you have an extreme amount of duplication in the original collection).

Answer (score -1):

If you want stable ordering with (nearly) the performance of a `HashSet`, then use a `LinkedHashSet`.  You will still get constant-time operations, whereas I would assume a `TreeSet` will get you logarithmic time.