# Unsorted HashSet in Java

Tags: java, hashset

*Code.*

```
Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>(3);
set.add("3 Lorem");
set.add("1 Lorem");
set.add("2 Lorem");
Iterator<String> iterator = set.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    String type = (String) iterator.next();
    System.out.println(type);
}
```

*Output.*

```
2 Lorem
3 Lorem
1 Lorem
```

This order looks strange to me. I add `3 Lorem`, `1 Lorem`, and then `2 Lorem`. Why are they in a different order in the output?

Comment: what's your question?

Comment: Why do you think there should be an order?

Comment: @LutzHorn, I thought it would in the order I used when adding.

Comment: What make you think this?

Comment: @LutzHorn, I didn't know it; now I know. By the way, it may be an interview question

Comment: @MaksimDmitriev : set are unordered

Comment: @HussainAkhtarWahid That's incorrect. The ordering of a set depends entirely on the implementation of a set. See for example the differences between `TreeSet`, `HashSet`, and `LinkedHashSet`.

Comment: It is scary to think that the OP may be interviewing for whatever job this is.

Comment: @Maksim Dmitriev: You're missing **Ipsum**!

Comment: @JasonC, what does _OP_ mean?

Comment: @JasonC : yeah , exactly , set is not ordered means , sets do not gaurantee the order you input the elements while iterating the sets , so sets do not maintain the order , thus are unordered

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html):

> This class implements the Set interface, backed by a hash table
>   (actually a HashMap instance). It makes no guarantees as to the
>   iteration order of the set; in particular, it does not guarantee that
>   the order will remain constant over time. This class permits the null
>   element.

if you intended to keep order better use [TreeSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html)  (but complexity will be log(n)

also check this post 
[Hashset vs Treeset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1463284/hashset-vs-treeset)

**EDIT** as pointed out by @Petar in order to maintain insertion order better use [LinkedHashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html)

and this [Dzone Article](http://java.dzone.com/articles/hashset-vs-treeset-vs) demonstrates comparison between all three with nice suit of example and performance

Comment: He should use a `LinkedHashSet` to maintain the insertion order, not a `TreeSet`.

Comment: @PetarMinchev yeah thanks for the pointer, now updated my answer

Answer (score 9):

Hash sets are **not supposed to be sorted**.

Technically they are sorted, but by the hash code (or a hash reduction thereof); and on hash collisions they may overflow into other buckets.

If you want an ordered set, use `TreeSet` instead. It usually is a bit slower, but sorted. If you want to retain the *insertion* order, use a `List` such as `ArrayList` or `LinkedList`.

There also is a hybrid, called `LinkedHashSet`, which allows fast `contains` operations, but maintains insertion order. Note that it won't have *duplicates* though.

Comment: He should use a `LinkedHashSet` to maintain the insertion order.

Answer (score 3):

Use a `LinkedHashSet` to maintain the insertion order.

Answer (score 1):

Use `TreeSet<String>();` or `TreeSet<String>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);` if you want to Sort the elements. Use List instead of Set If you need to maintain the insertion order.

Comment: He should use a `LinkedHashSet` to maintain the insertion order, not a `List`.

Comment: I think he wants to maintain the insertion order, not to sort.

Comment: `List` allows duplicates which is not desired as implied by the OP's original use of `Set`