# Random numbers without duplicate

Tags: java

```
public class startOrder {


public static void main(String[] args) {
int[] start = new int[45];

for(int i=0;i<start.length;i++)
{
    start[i] = (int)(Math.random()*45);
}

for(int i=0;i<start.length;i++)
{
    System.out.println(start[i]);
}
}

}
```

I want to make a simple program that just prints all random numbers between 1-45. The problem though is there's duplicate numbers among them, how can I make it to print numbers between 1-45 without any duplication. It's a program that generates a random start number.

Comment: Just add every already generated number to an array / list and check with `contains()` if that number has already been generated once - then skip it. Note: This may result in BAD performance if you like to generate random numbers from 1 to 40, while having bounds from 1 to 41.

Answer (score 4):

Fill a list with the preferred numbers, then shuffle it, for example using the build in library function like below.

```
List<Integer> myNumbers = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4, etc.);
Collections.shuffle(myNumbers);
```

Then simply iterate over the list.

Btw, this is called a random permutation.

Comment: +1 This is the only answer that doesn't involve generating unnecessary random numbers for an unknown amount of time, losing efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

You could fill a linked list with 1-45, and repeatedly remove one randomly selected index from the list.

Answer (score 0):

Create an array or some collection, populate it with the numbers, then shuffle it using two randoms.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a boolean array bArray of size 45 with all places set to false (which means that number is not picked yet).
2. Whenever you pick a number, let's say you picked 15, check if bArray[15] is false. If yes, pick that number and assign the bArray[15] to true (which means the number is now taken).

Repeat this till you have got all 45 numbers!

Comment: Somewhat inefficient...

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `HashSet`!

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Set<Integer> start = new HashSet<Integer>();

    while (start.size() <= 45)
    {
        start.add((int) (Math.random() * 45)+1);
    }

    for (int i: start)
    {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

A `Set` does not allow duplicates, so when you reach a size of 45, you have all unique numbers between 1 and 45! Also keep in mind that your random code generated a number between 0-44, which I fixed.

Comment: Well it will work, eventually....

Comment: @TonyHopkinson Yeah, not exactly efficient, but it sounds like a school assignment so I was trying to preserve the spirit of his code.

Answer (score 0):

Just use Set as such

```
Set<Integer> start = new HashSet<Integer>();
```

Set's are designed to eliminate duplicate values

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the `TreeSet` and `HashSet`. These collections will not store any duplicates.

Read more about them here:

HashSet ---> http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html

TreeSet ---> http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html

Also, read in another Stackoverflow post about HashSet vs TreeSet, I highly recommend reading it. Read the top comment: [Hashset vs Treeset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1463284/hashset-vs-treeset)