# Java: Hashset Vs TreeSet - when should I use over the other?

Tags: java, collections

All I have been reading lots of blogs on this subject but still I could not get clear idea when to use one over another hashset or tree set.

Taken an example:

1. I have a comparable objects. I have put them in HashSet. Now when (**only when I want**) i want to set to be sorted based on compareTo logic, I can call Collections.sort(object)
2. whereas Treeset by default always use the compareTo or compare(obj1, obj2) **all the time**. Hence performance will be hit with TreeSet but output will be same as #1 (Collections.sort).

Is this understanding correct?

Comment: [Does this help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1463284/hashset-vs-treeset)?

Answer (score 147, accepted):

**HashSet** is Implemented using a hash table. Elements are not ordered. The `add, remove,` and contains methods have constant time **complexity O(1)**.

**TreeSet** is implemented using a tree structure(red-black tree in algorithm book). The elements in a set are sorted, but the add, remove, and contains methods has time **complexity O(log (n)**). It offers several methods to deal with the ordered set like `first(), last(), headSet(), tailSet()`, etc.

1) First major difference between `HashSet` and `TreeSet` is performance. `HashSet` is faster than `TreeSet` and should be preferred choice if sorting of element is not required.

2) Second difference between `HashSet` and `TreeSet` is that `HashSet` allows null object but `TreeSet` doesn't allow null Object and throw `NullPointerException`, Why, because `TreeSet` uses `compareTo()` method to compare keys and `compareTo()` will throw `java.lang.NullPointerException`.

3) Another significant difference between `HashSet` and `TreeSet` is that , `HashSet` is backed by `HashMap` while `TreeSet` is backed by NavigableMap in Java.

4) One more difference between `HashSet` and `TreeSet` which is worth remembering is that HashSet uses `equals()` method to compare two object in Set and for detecting duplicates while `TreeSet` uses `compareTo()` method for same purpose. if `equals()` and `compareTo()` are not consistent, i.e. for two equal object equals should return true while `compareTo()` should return zero, than it will break contract of Set interface and will allow duplicates in Set implementations like TreeSet

5) Now most important difference between `HashSet` and `TreeSet` is ordering. `HashSet` doesn't guaranteed any order while `TreeSet` maintains objects in Sorted order defined by either `Comparable` or `Comparator` method in Java.

6) `TreeSet` does not allow to insert `Heterogeneous` objects. It will throw `classCastException` at `Runtime` if trying to add hetrogeneous objects, whereas `HashSet` allows hetrogeneous objects.

Comment: One More, Treeset is homogeneous means allow only same type of data while Hashset is heterogeneous.

Comment: "HashSet is faster than TreeSet and should be preferred choice if sorting of element is not required", this is partially correct

Comment: TreeSet is backed by NavigableMap not TreeMap

Comment: @ViyaanJhiingade corrected, thanks for pointing out