# removeAll() in ArrayList vs HashSet

Tags: java, arraylist, hashset, removeall

I found out that for quite big Arrays (over 1000 entries), the methods `A.removeAll(B)` is way faster on a `HashSet` than on an `ArrayList`.

Do you have an idea of how these methods are implemented and how this could explain that difference?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A set (and thus `HashSet` as well) contains at most one element of `B` and since `HashSet` uses hashes it is quite efficient to locate and remove that element. The overall complexity should thus be `O(1)` for removing all (that is one) `B`.

A list can contain any number of `B` in any location so removing all `B` has to check all elements. The overall complexity is `O(n)` since every element has to be checked if it is a `B`.

Edit:

If `B` represents a collection/array, i.e. a set of multiple elements, you'd multiply the above complexities by the size `m` of `B`, so you'll get `O(m)` for `HashSet` and `O(n * m)` for lists.

Edit 2:

Note that if you have a sorted list the complexity might be reduced to `O(log(n))` or `O(log(n) * m)`. For that to work the code removing the actual elements would have to *know* the list is sorted though and since `ArrayList` is not guaranteed to be sorted it can't make that optimization.

Comment: So you mean that the complexity in an `ArrayList` it is about O(n2) ?

Comment: @Arcyno where you do get `O(n2)` (as in `O(n * n)`) from? If you mean `B` to be a collection or array please see my edit.

Comment: There is no such thing as "the complexity in an `ArrayList`".  Specific operations on `ArrayList`s have specific time complexities.  The time complexity of `ArrayList` *removal* is generally thought of as O(N).

Answer (score 1):

Basically the reason for both is the time complexity that these specific implementations are trying to achive for theyr respectiv operations.

The time complexity for the `ArrayList` remove method is `O(n - index)` [source from When to use LinkedList over ArrayList?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/322715/when-to-use-linkedlist-over-arraylist)

While the remove method of the `HashSet` offers constant time complexity `O(1)` [source from Hashset vs Treeset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1463284/hashset-vs-treeset)