# How do I save common words from two arrays into a third array?

Tags: java, arrays, string

I am trying to save all common words from arr1 and arr2 and then store to arr3.

```java
String[] arr1 = {"pEace", "happiness", "Gives", "So", "aaa"};
String[] arr2 = {"pEace", "HappiNess", "joy", "give", "AAA", "enjoy", "learN"};

int k = 0;
String[] arr3 = new String[0];
for (int i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < arr2.length; j++) {
        if (arr1[i].equalsIgnoreCase(arr2[j])) {
            System.out.println(arr1[i]);
            arr3[k] = arr1[i];
            k++;
        }
    }
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr3));
```

Comment: String[] arr3 = new String[0]; here instead of Zero use length of arr1

Comment: Life lesson: Never say simply "I'm getting an error"; bosses (and coworkers, too, but _especially_ bosses) hate that.  There's always more to an error than just "error".

Comment: By the way… [*Java, find intersection of two arrays*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17863319/642706)

Answer (score 2):

The init size of arr3 is 0

> String[] arr3 = new String[0];

You should init with size is total length of arr1 and arr2 or use [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ArrayList.html). On that example are 12

Comment: Number of common elements will not exceed length of smaller array. `String[] arr3 = new String[Math.min(arr1.length, arr2.length)];` should do it.

Comment: Thank you for help but still I am not getting the right result. I know the result should be 
 [ pEace, happiness, aaa ] these 3 strings I am trying to save on arr3, but my resulte is come up like this [null, null, null, null, null, null]

Comment: You are missing import java.util.Arrays; import statement on top of the class.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert these *arrays* to *collections* and then use the [`retainAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#retainAll(java.util.Collection)) method. It works differently in different collections.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lZJdS8MwFIbv@yvCrjrRDns7HZRZdKAVVvFGZMQ2zNQsKUlWGWO/vebELoujY5iLnp6vJ@c9pMINvhI14VX51bZ0VQupUWWC0VpTFl2Mg6BefzBaoIJhpdATphxtA2ROF1caa2MaQUu0Mtkw15Ly5ds7wnKphl0xnNEITQVviLkBS4k3CmmBCsEYKTQVXLlCjyCv0S3aDuoUF2RwiQafuK4pJ0qBc08bYn9yAV@MMRhGsOSD3bgXF//FPQAu63CV2IBZGirYJEn2uAxwjjd1I9/8oidWBUyaWF0RVo9U6RDGH47P9cV9ffHQu9AszhZA0gVdxMGYcWAITr697CT0RuhvivubXJcFR7gsE8ZCK9VDWoCfjI9b40gSbV4GFFiUX5BvlCarSKx1VJuJNOO25lj/iyQkJwf1ne9kKOKk71OT7iVG0yRPF7MsT7N89jJ7TRfP87t07knogcX/hjkajHJqWUA@uSubPKwKOGc2BR0dfRfs2vYH)

```java
// Convert arrays to collections
String[] arr1 = {"pEace", "happiness", "Gives", "So", "aaa", "learn"};
String[] arr2 = {"pEace", "HappiNess", "joy", "give", "AAA", "learN"};

Collection<String> coll1 = Arrays.asList(arr1);
Collection<String> coll2 = Arrays.asList(arr2);
```

```java
// ArrayList
ArrayList<String> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> list2 = new ArrayList<>();

list1.addAll(coll1);
list2.addAll(coll2);

list2.retainAll(list1);

System.out.println(list2); // [pEace]
```

```java
// TreeSet
TreeSet<String> set1 = new TreeSet<>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
TreeSet<String> set2 = new TreeSet<>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);

set1.addAll(coll1);
set2.addAll(coll2);

set2.retainAll(set1);

System.out.println(set2); // [AAA, HappiNess, learN, pEace]
```

---

<sup>See also: [Is it possible that TreeSet equals HashSet but not HashSet equals TreeSet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63067107/15495739)</sup>